# If a git rebase is found to be in-progress, are the local files affected?

Tags: git, web, server, merge, rebase

I have a website being served, and someone began (but did not complete) an interactive rebase.  I want to know if aborting the rebase will affect the actual current state of the files being served.  Since I am ok with the state of the website as it appears when I visit it, I would guess that aborting the rebase would not affect the contents of the files being served, but rather there are changes incoming that would appear on the website if I were to `git release --continue`.

Comment: Wait, you are doing the rebase on a web server in the working tree of a live website??

Comment: Unfortunately a former employee was.  And I am supposed to clean things up.  That it what I found when I entered the server directory.

Comment: Do you have a staging server where you can reproduce this state and experiment without fear of breaking the live website?

Comment: I am just going to cp the directory out and then see how things look after aborting the rebase.  Then I can restore the original back in place if things are really broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rebase is a series of merges. (Actually it's a series of cherry picks but a cherry pick is a merge.) A merge is enacted in the working tree. Aborting will reset the working tree back to what it was like before the rebase started, which therefore is probably not the situation as you see it now.

However, it might be, namely if the rebase never even started (the todo list was formed but never used, for instance). And it is trivial to find out: just diff the working tree with the situation before the rebase started (which you can obtain from the reflog).

Comment: Basically it would help to know why the rebase ever stopped.